# match text after first match

Tags: regex, grep

I need to write a regular expression that can do the following, it should return the text after the matched string, between the first set of quote marks, given the quote matched string isn't proceed by a different string. So:

`def my_method "param/1" "param2"` should return nothing and

`my_method "param/3" "param4"` should return only "param/3"

So far I have `(?<!def )my_method (["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`

but this also matches the my_method part which it shouldn't.

Comment: What flavour are you needing it in?

Comment: It will be run using grep

Comment: You may try something like `(?<=(?<!def )my_method )(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1`

Comment: Thanks for the help, that does work on the online regex tester but if I run the command `grep -r -P -o -h '(?<=(?<!def )my_method )(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1'` I get an error `syntax error near unexpected token `)'` sorry if I'm being stupid

Comment: would this `my_method "param5" text` a valid input?

Comment: yup, but it should just return "param5"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for grep with perl favor that retrieves the first stuff between quotes:

```
grep -Po '(?<!def my_method )(?<=my_method )"[^"]*"'
```

This code made some assertions:

- The only unwanted match is the one that starts with `def`. I added this because of my limited understanding of the problem.
- There must be one space betweem `my_method` and the first set of quotes. This is due to a regex lookbehind limitation.

Explanation:

- `grep -P` is for perl falvour
- `grep -o` is for keeping only the matched parts
- `(?<!def my_method )` - this is the beginning what we don't want
- `(?<=my_method )` - this is the beginning that we want. This is a lookbehind so it will not be part of the match
- `)"[^"]*"` - this is what we want: something between quotes.

Alternatively, you can try `sed` too:

```
grep -P '(?<!def)\s*my_method[^"]+"[^"]+"' | sed 's/^[^"]\+\("[^"]*"\).*$/\1/g'
```